# SELECT MAX Giving duplicate results?

Tags: sql

I’m using Select MAX to get the newest [CreatedDateTime] however I get duplicates in my query instead of the single result? My SQL query looks like this;

```
SELECT DISTINCT
i.[RecID] as AssigneeID,
t.[Owner],
t.[CreatedDateTime]
FROM Incident as i
Left Join Task as t
On i.[RecID] =  t.[ParentLink_RecID] 
WHERE
(t.[CreatedDateTime] IN (SELECT MAX(t.[CreatedDateTime])
        FROM Task as t
       GROUP BY t.[ParentLink_RecID]))
AND i.[Status] <> 'Closed'
AND t.[OwnerTeam] IS NOT NULL
Order By i.[RecID] ASC
```

Sample data added from duplicate question:

```
AssigneeID                          CreatedDateTime
E94D6F547A73430BA75758C79D5BD8DB    28/05/2013 10:25
E94D6F547A73430BA75758C79D5BD8DB    28/05/2013 10:32
CB208EB6BCC24E1791F946F01D6AF97B    26/03/2013 15:14
CB208EB6BCC24E1791F946F01D6AF97B    16/05/2013 15:20
BE14926E300E45AD8A9A949114CE8026    29/04/2013 10:27
BE14926E300E45AD8A9A949114CE8026    01/05/2013 08:41
```

Any assistance would be appreciated

Comment: Please post your table & some of the contents, it will be much easier to help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `in` clause is selecting `CreatedDateTime` values that are the max for **any** `ParentLink_RecID` value, not just the max for the **specific** `RecID` value - if you only require the RecID and the latest date, try:

```
SELECT i.[RecID] as AssigneeID, max(t.[CreatedDateTime]) CreatedDateTime
FROM Incident as i
Join Task as t On i.[RecID] =  t.[ParentLink_RecID] 
WHERE i.[Status] <> 'Closed'
  AND t.[OwnerTeam] IS NOT NULL
group by i.[RecID]
Order By i.[RecID] DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get that if there is more than one record with the same value for `CreatedDateTime`. I think the following query is what you want, where we just select the one row with the most recent created datetime and filter on that:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
i.[RecID] as AssigneeID,
t.[Owner],
t.[CreatedDateTime]
FROM Incident as i
Left Join Task as t
On i.[RecID] =  t.[ParentLink_RecID] 
WHERE t.[ParentLink_RecID] = (SELECT TOP 1 t.[ParentLink_RecID]
                              FROM Task as t
                              ORDER BY t.[CreatedDateTime] DESC)
AND i.[Status] <> 'Closed'
AND t.[OwnerTeam] IS NOT NULL
Order By i.[RecID] ASC
```

Comment: Hi Erik,
I tried your suggestion and still got 2 results, [RecID] as AssigneeID is the same in both however the [CreatedDateTime] is different? Please see below
AssigneeID     Owner  CreatedDateTime
9F39162608214E97A3C375E28E776061  Bob  2013-05-29 17:10:11.000
9F39162608214E97A3C375E28E776061  Bill  2013-05-29 20:40:34.000
I just need it to return the second row with the newest datetime
Thanks in avance for any further assistance
Wayne