# SELECT MAX(DATE) from another table with Left Join?

Tags: sql, select

I'm having problems with my SELECT MAX(DATE) code; when I run my query I get 3000+ rows as expected however I'm getting duplicate rows for [AssigneeID] instead of just the one with the MAX(DATE)? Please see my code below and a sample of the table after running the query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
i.[RecID] as AssigneeID,
t.[CreatedDateTime]
FROM Incident as i
Left Join Task as t
On i.[RecID] =  t.[ParentLink_RecID] 
WHERE
(t.[CreatedDateTime] IN (SELECT MAX(t.[CreatedDateTime])
             FROM Task as t
             GROUP BY t.[ParentLink_RecID]))
AND i.[Status] <> 'Closed'
AND t.[OwnerTeam] IS NOT NULL
Order By i.[RecID] DESC

AssigneeID                          CreatedDateTime
E94D6F547A73430BA75758C79D5BD8DB    28/05/2013 10:25
E94D6F547A73430BA75758C79D5BD8DB    28/05/2013 10:32
CB208EB6BCC24E1791F946F01D6AF97B    26/03/2013 15:14
CB208EB6BCC24E1791F946F01D6AF97B    16/05/2013 15:20
BE14926E300E45AD8A9A949114CE8026    29/04/2013 10:27
BE14926E300E45AD8A9A949114CE8026    01/05/2013 08:41
```

Thanks in advance for any guidance

Comment: Duplicate of [SELECT MAX Giving duplicate results?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17121519/select-max-giving-duplicate-results) - please work to improve your existing question, instead of asking what is effectively the same question over and over.

Comment: @MarkBannister . . . Why did you delete your answer?  It looks correct to me.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: I entered that answer before I realised this was a duplicate question. I've entered the same answer against the original question - I don't want the answer entered against the duplicate.

Comment: @MarkBannister . . . I upvoted it there and voted to close this version.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: I have, still getting used to posting questions..

Answer (score 2):

add a GROUP BY statement:

```
SELECT
i.[RecID] as AssigneeID,
t.[CreatedDateTime]
FROM Incident as i
Left Join Task as t
On i.[RecID] =  t.[ParentLink_RecID] 
WHERE
(t.[CreatedDateTime] IN (SELECT MAX(t.[CreatedDateTime])
             FROM Task as t
             GROUP BY t.[ParentLink_RecID]))
AND i.[Status] <> 'Closed'
AND t.[OwnerTeam] IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY i.[RecID]
Order By i.[RecID] DESC
```

Comment: Mark, Perfect many thanks for the assistance, just one question I need to add another column t.[Owner]? sorry if its a stupid question Im new to SQL.

Comment: @SQL_Newbie . . . Why are you thanking Mark?  You should be accepting his answer on the original version of the question.

Comment: If you add additional columns to your SELECT you will also add them to your GROUP BY, unless they are AGGREGATES, like SUM/MAX/MIN etc.

Comment: @Goat_CO If I add additional columns and group by them I get duplicates in my AssigneeID again?

Comment: You'll get combinations of any non-aggregate fields, not duplicates with a group by.